# Execute Async lambda in main thread?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8

I have some asynchronous code in my Project that executes a lambda that takes several seconds to run, and executes another lambda on completion of the first. Somewhat like this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return longExecution("Hello Test");
}).thenAccept(text -> {
    mustBeInMainThread(text);
});
```

Now this is just an example. But I need the `thenAccept` lambda execution to happen in the main thread, and not in a separate thread.

Is this at all possible, and if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can not tell it to run an action in an arbitrary thread, as the thread must be ready to execute such actions and not being busy doing entirely different things. If you are fine with letting you main thread being blocked, waiting to execute such action, it's as easy as `mustBeInMainThread(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> longExecution("Hello Test")).join());` which lets the initiating thread wait for the result in `join()`, followed by calling the other method with the result. But, of course, there is no point in doing the first method asynchronously then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell it to run in the main thread using the future's constructs, but you can get the result and use it:

```
CompletableFuture<MyObject> future = 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> longExecution("Hello Test"));

//do other things in main thread while async task runs
```

You can then use the result in the main thread by waiting:

```
//get result and call method in main thread:
mustBeInMainThread(future.join());
```

Comment: But doesn't waiting defeat the purpose of asynchronous code?

Comment: @I.Renk Not in this case. You only wait when main thread must have the result of `longExecution`. If you see the comment after the completable future call, you can run other code/operations **while** the async code/task is running. Chances are `future.join()` will be called after the long execution is already completed.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much! :)